# Gedit 2.3 plugins on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, plugins, gedit

I'm trying to install the [Advanced Find](https://code.google.com/archive/p/advanced-find/) plugin for Gedit 2.3 on Windows 7, but so far I haven't been able to. Since the directory for plugins is `/home/username/.local/share/gedit/plugins` for Linux, I went to `C:\Program Files\gedit\share\gedit-2\plugins` and tried placing the files there, but it still won't appear in the plugins settings. Do you guys know how plugins are installed?

Comment: It's a 32bit machine, which is why I'm using Gedit 2.3 and not 3.2 (latest, I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How plugins are installed on Windows?

> For Windows
>
> .lang files go in:
>
> ```
> %ProgramFiles%\gedit\share\gtksourceview-2.0\language-specs\
> ```
>
> plugins go in:
>
> ```
> %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\gedit\plugins\
> ```
>
> styles go in:
>
> ```
> %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\gedit\styles\
> ```

Source [Customize Gedit for Groovy/Grails](https://grails.org/wiki/Gedit)

Comment: Thank you! I don't know how you found that, I spent the morning searching the internet for that little piece of info...

Comment: @KardNails lol. Google-fu! I searched for "gedit windows plugin installation". 30s to find and a minute or 2 to write the answer :)

Comment: Truly weird. Could it be the google localization? Because I searched the exact same thing and found nothing. :D

Comment: @KardNails https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit is the second result for me ...

Comment: After installing Gedit 3.20.1 for Windows I have the gedit folder in `AppData\Local` (not in `AppData\Roaming`).